# Unresolved External Symbol Error 2001

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am getting error LNK2001 when i try to use my dll project in another project.

Code for my header File is

```
#ifdef VIZFUNCTIONSDLL_EXPORTS
#define VIZFUNCTIONSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define VIZFUNCTIONSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

namespace VizFunctions
{
  class SUMCLASS
 {
     public:
        static VIZFUNCTIONSDLL_API double Test(double a);

 };
}
```

Code for my Source file is

```
// VizFunctions.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
```

//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "VizFunctions.h"
#include <stdexcept>

namespace VizFunctions
{

 double SUMCLASS::Test(double a)
 {
   return a;
 }

}
```

Error message

```
Error 13 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static double 
    __cdecl VizFunctions::SUMCLASS::Test(double)" 
    (?Test@SUMCLASS@VizFunctions@@SANN@Z) referenced in function "public: 
    int __thiscall CRectangle::PlugInNewGeom(int)" (?PlugInNewGeom@CRectangle@@QAEHH@Z) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\vizrt\Viz3\plugin\src\examples\rectangle\Rectangle.obj SampleRectangle
```

Comment: Add your full error message to the question, please.

Comment: Are you linking against the DLL? Have you consulted the [canonical linker error question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1782465)?

Comment: Error 13 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static double __cdecl VizFunctions::SUMCLASS::Test(double)" (?Test@SUMCLASS@VizFunctions@@SANN@Z) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CRectangle::PlugInNewGeom(int)" (?PlugInNewGeom@CRectangle@@QAEHH@Z) C:\Program Files (x86)\vizrt\Viz3\plugin\src\examples\rectangle\Rectangle.obj SampleRectangle

Comment: Error Message By Visual Studio.

Comment: I am inserting my Dll project in an existing project and in Framework and references adding the dll Project.

Comment: In your question you wrote it was `LNK2001` error, in your error message it's `LNK2019`. Why?

Comment: @sumitkang Did you get the attach to debugger to work with Vizrt ?

Answer (score 2):

You will see this error if you aren't linking against the **Import Library** for the dll.  The Import Library is a bit of glue code that will load the DLL for you and map the exported dll functions automatically.

Ensure that your DLL project is creating an import library in Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Import Library

[image: Import library setting]

If you add the dll *project* as a dependency of your executable (rather than just the dll) then this will automatically link against the import library and resolve the link error.  If you don't have it as a dependency then you will need to explicitly add the import library to Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't include static library which is generated when you build dll to your new project.